# mysql sum() is not working. How can I solve it?

Tags: php, mysql

I am using php 7.2...

The code is working fine

```
<?php 

    $add=mysqli_query($conn,'SELECT ac_id, SUM(amount)  from stac where ac_id="117" '); 
    while($row1=mysqli_fetch_array($add)) { $mark=$row1['SUM(amount)'];  
    echo $mark ; }?>
```

but the code below is not working. Please help me.

```
<?php 
  $ac_id=$_POST['ac_id'];


    $add=mysqli_query($conn,'SELECT ac_id, SUM(amount)  from stac where ac_id=$ac_id '); 
    while($row1=mysqli_fetch_array($add)) { $mark=$row1['SUM(amount)'];  
    echo $mark ; }?>
```

Comment: What about it isn't working? Have you checked for [mysqli errors](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php)? By the way, if you're going to use variables, you really ought to use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). It will save on quoting headaches.

Comment: `SUM()` is an function of `mySQL` not `php`.

Comment: have your query like this SELECT ac_id, SUM(amount) as sum_val  from stac where ac_id=$ac_id and use sum_val as key in php array

Comment: what is the schema for this?

Comment: where is `$_POST['ac_id']` coming from?

Comment: If the column is varchar, you can't SUM on that. You would need to cast it.

Comment: Shyful74  did you checked the answer below?

Answer (score 0):

Its seems like your id field is not integer so you should pass variable into single quote (') and also pass your query in double quote (") so variable will parse correctly.

**Replace your query with this**

```
$add=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT ac_id, SUM(amount)  from stac where ac_id='$ac_id' ");
```

Answer (score 0):

Did     you forget to add the group by when using an aggregate?
Like so:

```
 SELECT ac_id, SUM(amount)  from stac where ac_id=$ac_id group by ac_id
```

Answer (score -1):

Try changing your query to

```
$add=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT ac_id, SUM(amount)  from stac where ac_id='$ac_id' ");
```